# how to return value as response in @before, with out moving to the controller (using AOP)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop

I'm using AOP concept and the dispatcher sends the call to before advice method. In that, how to return value in before advice method with out getting into controller?

```
public Object cache(JoinPoint jointPoint, RedisCache redisCache) throws Throwable{
String data = getRedisService().getValue(redisKey);
if(data != null){return "hi";}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[before advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-schema-advice-before):

```
Before advice runs before a matched method execution
```

[around advice](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-schema-advice-around)

```
It has the opportunity to do work both before and after the method
executes, and to determine when, how, and even if, the method actually 
gets to execute at all
```